# Is .config called other things for different system languages?

Tags: configuration, language-support, xdg-base-directory

I'm making an application that reads/writes to files in the ~/.config folder; however, I want to make sure it works under all systems. Is `.config` called other things for different system languages? Is there a better way of accessing its value than using a hardcoded `.config` string? (a la an environment variable)

What is the best practice for this? If there is no established best practice, what is the simplest approach that guarantees the desired result?

Comment: Why not make your own folder specific to your own app. `~/.myapp`

Comment: When asking questions please use a proper, concise title, and not something like "~/.config folder".

Comment: @EdManet: this would pollute the home directory. I remember the days before XDG was widely supported, and my home directory was really a mess. To be honest, my home directory is still messy because of applications that do not follow XDG.

Comment: @RolandiXor sorry, I'm used to posting on StackOverflow, where expressive titles are discouraged (at least my titles are regularly pruned of meaning). I'll remember that this community welcomes sane titles. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That configuration directory is specified by the [**XDG Base Directory Specification**](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) standard.

The answer to your question is in the [Environment variables](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#variables) section:

> `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` defines the base directory relative to which user specific configuration files should be stored. If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is either not set or empty, a default equal to `$HOME/.config` should be used.

Be sure to also read [Basics](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#basics), to ensure that you are using the right directories for the right files.

You may also want to know what to do when `$HOME` is not set. This is not specified by XDG, however what some applications do is to throw an error and exit. Alternatively, you can get the current user ID via `getuid(2)` and use `getpwuid(3)` to extract the home directory.

Answer (score 5):

It's part of the [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html):

> $XDG_CONFIG_HOME defines the base directory relative to which user specific  configuration files should be stored. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is either not set or empty, a default equal to $HOME/.config should be used.